# Strange JPanel background glitching

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, jcomponent

I have some identical extended JPanel instances each with transparent background done with `Color(255, 255, 255, 0);`. When `mousePressed()` of any JPanel is triggered, it's background sets to solid color.

Problem is, **for the first few miliseconds** after mouse pressed (lazy person would just overcome it) **the background becomes an image of the JComponent pressed before**.

What I hope is that there is some "memory cleaner" or some method of managing those JComponent actions that I don't know about...

edit:

```
        addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
        boolean mousePressed;
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {}
        Timer timer;
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            setBackground(new Color(255, 255, 255, 20));
            setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new Color(255, 255, 255, 100), 3));
            repaint();
            timer = new Timer();
            mousePressed = true;
            timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() { //keep jpanel position relative to mouse position
                Point pC = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation();
                Point pP = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation();
                Point sP = getLocation();
                public void run() {
                    if(mousePressed) {
                        pC = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation();
                        setLocation(sP.x + (pC.x - pP.x), sP.y + (pC.y - pP.y));
                        pP = pC;
                        sP = getLocation(); 
                    } else {
                        pC = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation();
                        pP = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation();
                        sP = getLocation();
                    }
                }
            },  5, 5);
        }
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            mousePressed = false;
            setBackground(null);
            setBorder(null);
            repaint();
            timer.cancel();
        }
```

Comment: Could you share your code with us so we can help you without guessing?

Comment: `...each with transparent background ...` Swing doesn't handle transparent backgrounds correctly. See: [Backgrounds With Transparency](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/31/backgrounds-with-transparency/) for an explanation of the problem and a solution.

Comment: That was exactly the thing I was looking for - knowing what's the problem. Solved it thanks to the link you posted. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Solved by overriding** `paintComponent()` **method and setting opaque to** `false`

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        g.setColor(getBackground());
        g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        super.paintComponent(g);
    } 
};
panel.setOpaque(false); // background of parent will be painted first
panel.setBackground( new Color(255, 0, 0, 20) );
frame.add(panel);
```